# Check if service reference WSDL link is online

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, windows-phone-8, service-reference

I'm currently working on Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone. I'm using a service reference with a WSDL link in it to get some data. Is there any way to check if my service reference/link is online?

Here is my proxy:

```
var proxy = new StorageClient();
```

I tried this but it always says "created":

```
proxy.State();
```

Comment: Yeah, call it and find out.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I'm already calling it to get data. I'm asking if there are any methods to check that, like `state`. But the problem with `state` is that it always says created.

Comment: The definition of "online" is "I call it, and it returns data, so I know it was online when I called it".

Comment: Yes I agree but that leads to another question that I asked here a few days ago and nobody answered. Following your idea, I need to catch an exception when it doesn't return anything. The problem is that I'm not getting anywhere that way. Since nobody answered that question, here I am asking for another way to check if my service reference is online.

Comment: "Service References" are not "online". The client proxy either allows you to call the service and get a response, or it doesn't.